# javascript remove functions in async.parallel

Tags: javascript, function, async.js, asynccallback

this question may seem easy but I have 0 experience in javascript and got confused with the call-back functions.

The original code was doing some "async.each" with "async.parallel" stuff.

```
function fillMap(listElements, elementMap, params, callBack) {
    async.each(listElements, function findElement(listElement, forEachCallBack) {
        async.parallel(
            {
                fun1: function getUniqueElement(parallelCallBack) {
                    params.getResponse1(parallelCallBack);
                },
                fun2: function getElement(parallelCallBack) {
                    params.getResponse2(parallelCallBack);
                }

            },
            function fillElement(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    return forEachCallBack(err);
                }
                elementMap[listElement] = res.body;
                forEachCallBack();
            });
    }, callBack);
}
```

Now I don't need, say, the first function in async.parallel, I just need "getElement" but not "getUniqueElement". How should I remove it from the async.parallel body? And I don't I need the "async.parallel" But I don't know how can I call the "getElement" with "fillElement" still receives the response body..

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the getUniqueElement from async.parallel

```
function fillMap(listElements, elementMap, params, callBack) {
    async.each(listElements, function findElement(listElement, forEachCallBack) {
        async.parallel(
            {
                fun2: function getElement(parallelCallBack) {
                    params.getResponse2(parallelCallBack);
                }
            },
            function fillElement(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    return forEachCallBack(err);
                }
                elementMap[listElement] = res.body;
                forEachCallBack();
            });
    }, cb);
}
```

Removing the whole async.parallel block

```
function fillMap(listElements, elementMap, params, callBack) {
    async.each(listElements, function findElement(listElement, forEachCallBack) {
        var fillElement = function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                return forEachCallBack(err);
            }
            elementMap[listElement] = res.body;
            forEachCallBack();
        }

        var getElement = function (callback) {
            params.getResponse2(callback);
        };

        getElement(fillElement);

    }, callBack);
}
```

Try to go through the api https://github.com/caolan/async
If any doubt feel free to ask.

Comment: Are you able to get it or you need some help

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion. however I got a typeError: "undefined is not a function" when going through some test cases..

Comment: which one you used, without parallel? can you provide some more detail of the error

Comment: "at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:345:15)" and also

Comment: also in "var getElement=function(callback)" and the "cb" I made a mistake, the "cb" should be "callBack" in function "fillMap".

Comment: Try with the changes. all the best